# Seemingly Identical Random Variables with Different Variances

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, variance

In my probability class, we did the following problem regarding expected values/variance:

Consider an experiment where you roll a fair, 6-sided dice until you see a 6. Let $T$ be a random variable denoting the total sum, including the final 6. Also, consider an experiment where you roll a fair, 6-sided dice until you see a 1. Let $S$ be a random variable denoting the total sum, including the final 1.

a) Which is larger, $E[T]$ or $E[S]$?

We showed that $E[T] = E[S] = 21$, by conditioning $T$ and $S$ on a random variable $N$ denoting the total number of rolls.

b) Which is larger, $Var[T]$ or $Var[S]$?

Here, we showed that $Var[T] > Var[S]$, by again conditioning on $N$.

However, I took a different approach to (b). I noted that when we consider the variance of a random variable, we are really concerned with the deviation between a value the random variable can take and it's expectation, not that actual numbers themselves. Also, note each roll is independent of the others. Therefore, let $T = T_1 + T_2 + ... + T_N$, where $T_i$ is the value rolled on the i-th roll, and define $S_i$ similarly. I believe $Var[T_i] = Var[S_i]$ on any given roll before the final one, as in both experiments, the deviations can take the values $-2, 1, 0, 1, 2$ with probability $\frac{1}{5}$. Furthermore, on the last roll of each experiment, the deviations between the values rolled and the expectation are identical, taking the value $3$. If all of the deviations are identical then, how are the variances different?

Note: I do understand how to compute the variances by conditioning on $N$, and accept that my answer was wrong. However, I'm specifically looking for where the logic breaks down in my argument, as it seems that the deviations and probabilities are the same for each experiment, which to me implies that the variances should be equal as well.

Comment: In your intuitive calculations, where are you considering the fact that the number of variables $N$ that you sum is also random?

Comment: If you are using the conditional variance formula, you get $$Var(T) = E[\underbrace{Var(T|N)}] + Var(E[T|N])$$  Your argument intuitively shows that the variance in the underbrace is the same function of $N$ as $Var(S|N)$, that is, $Var(T|N) = Var(S|N)$.  However, the second part will be different because $E[T|N]=(N-1)3 + 6 = 3N+3$, but $E[S|N]=(N-1)4 + 1 = 4N-3$.  And so it seems $Var(S)>Var(T)$, which is flipped from what you wrote in the question. Intuitively it is larger for $S$ because the coefficient $4$ is multiplying $N$ and so that magnifies the variance.

Comment: @Michael I understand what you said - however, where does the logic break down in the following steps?

1) Define $T = T_1 + ... + T_N$.

2) We know $Var[T] = Var[T_1 + ... + T_N]$

3) As all $T_i$ are independent, $Var[T] = Var[T_1] + ... + Var[T_N]$

4) We apply the same logic to $S_i$, and note the symmetry.

Comment: The logic breaks down because $N$ is a random variable, not a fixed constant.  So what do you mean by $Var(T_1) + ... + Var(T_N)$?  How many terms are in the $...$? Can you write it more formally as a summation $\sum$? (no). It looks like the number of terms is random, and so it cannot be the same as the (nonrandom) number $Var(T)$. In contrast, if $k$ is a fixed constant and $\{T_1, ..., T_k\}$ are pairwise independent then indeed $Var(T_1 + ... + T_k) = Var(T_1) + ... + Var(T_k)$. Equivalently, $Var(\sum_{i=1}^k T_i) = \sum_{i=1}^k Var(T_i)$.

Comment: But if we condition we get: $$Var(T|N=k) = Var(T_1 + ... + T_{k-1}+6|N=k)=(k-1)Var(T_1|N=k) $$ and $$Var(S|N=k)=Var(S_1+...+S_{k-1}+1|N=k)=(k-1)Var(S_1|N=k)$$ but for  $k\in\{2, 3, 4, ...\}$ we have $Var(T_1|N=k)=Var(S_1|N=k)= \frac{1}{5}[2^2+1^2+0+1^2+2^2]$ and for $k=1$ we have $Var(T_1|N=1)=Var(S_1|N=1)=0$.

Comment: Got it - thanks!